# MATLAB/Octave: Adjust tick position/alignment for colorbar axis

Tags: matlab, alignment, octave, colorbar

My matrix contains discrete values `1`, `2` and `3`, which (in this case) are codes for `red`, `green` and `blue`. The colorbar shows these labels at positions, where I initially would not have expected them to be. I guess it has to do with the way, the colors are assigned (e. g. `2.4` isn't `green`, but `blue`), which doesn't assume discrete values.

I was hoping for a setting like "`TickLabelAlignment`" or something like that, but couldn't find anything. So I had to "manually" adjust the positions, which was successful. Yet, is there a more universal way to do this? I feel like I'm using a workaround.

Example:

```
% set gnuplot as graphics toolkit, set custum colormap and create exemplary matrix
graphics_toolkit('gnuplot');
colormap([1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);
A = randi([1 3], 5, 5);

% plot with standard settings
subplot (2, 1, 1);
imagesc(A);
caxis([1 3]);
mycb = colorbar();
set(mycb, 'YTick', [1 2 3], 'YTickLabel', {'red', 'green', 'blue'});

% plot with adjusted tick positions (the way I want the colorbar to look like)
subplot (2, 1, 2);
imagesc(A);
caxis([1 3]);
mycb = colorbar();
set(mycb, 'YTick', [4/3 2 8/3], 'YTickLabel', {'red', 'green', 'blue'});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no support for colormaps which only support integer math. Best thing you can do is to generalize the math:

```
% calculate the points where the colour segments start/end
b = linspace(1,n,n+1);
% calculate the centers;
c = mean([b(1:end-1);b(2:end)]);
```

Which for n=3 (three colours) calculates the positions you used above.